# Find all odd positive integers $n$ for which there exists odd positive integers $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ such that $x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2=n^4$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, diophantine-equations, integers

> Find all odd positive integers $n$ for which there exists odd positive integers $x_1,x_2,..,x_n$ such that
> $$x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2=n^4\,.$$

***My work so far:***

1. For $n=3$, the equation $$x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=81$$
   has no solutions because if a solution exists the, in modulo $4$, we have
   $$3\equiv 1\pmod{4}$$
   which is a contradiction.

2. $n\ge 5$?

*I need help here.*

Comment: Only a remark: if you take $n=m^2$, $m$ odd, then $x_k=m^3$ for all $k $ is a solution.

Comment: Is this a contest problem?

Comment: @almagest: Yes. It is the problem of the book "Collection of contest problems 2007-2008"

Comment: @Roman83 I have added the tag.  This tag is useful for highlighting that the problem is more likely to require thought than knowledge! As I have just discovered to my cost, having spent 5 mins failing to solve it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

all odd squares are $1 \pmod 8.$ This includes $n^4.$ Meanwhile,
$$ x_1^2 +x_2^2+ \cdots+ x_n^2 \equiv n \pmod 8. $$ So it is necessary to have $n \equiv 1 \pmod 8.$

In the other direction, all numbers $k \equiv 3 \pmod 8$ are the sum of three odd squares. This is a result of Gauss, and equivalent to the fact that all positive integers ae the sum of three triangular numbers, including $0$ if needed.

As a result, take any $n \equiv 1 \pmod 8.$ Take $x_4, x_5, \ldots, x_n$ to be anything (odd) you like, as long as the sum of squares is below $n^4.$ The leftover requires
$$ x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 = n^4 - \left( x_4^2 + \cdots+ x_n^2 \right) $$
which can always be solved in (odd) integers.

After Greg's comment, found a fairly greedy solution that does not require quoting Gauss. We have $n \equiv 1 \pmod 8.$ Note $37 \equiv 5 \pmod 8.$

Let
$$  K = \frac{3n - 3}{8}, $$
$$   W = \frac{5n - 37}{8}, $$
so that
$$ K + W = n-5, $$
$$ 9K + W = 4n-8. $$
The solution will have $K$ of the $x_j$ equal to $3,$ so those squares are $9,$ and their sum is $9K.$ We will also have $W$ of the $x_j$ set to $1,$ so their sum is just $W.$ Then, with a total of $n$ (odd) squares,
$$ \color{red}{ (n^2 - 2)^2 + n^2 + n^2 + n^2 + (n-2)^2 + 9K + W = n^4}   $$
With $n=9$ we get $K=3, W=1, $ $ \; \; 9^4 = 6561,$ then
$$ 79^2 + 9^2 + 9^2 + 9^2 + 7^2 + 9 \cdot 3 + 1 = 6241 + 81 + 81 + 81 + 49 + 27 + 1 = 6561. $$

With $n=17$ we get $K=6, W=6, $ $ \; \; 17^4 = 83521,$ then
$$ 287^2 + 17^2 + 17^2 + 17^2 + 15^2 + 9 \cdot 6 + 6 = 82369 + 289 + 289 + 289 + 225 + 54 + 6 = 83521. $$

With $n=25$ we get $K=9, W=11, $ $ \; \; 25^4 = 390625,$ then
$$ 623^2 + 25^2 + 25^2 + 25^2 + 23^2 + 9 \cdot 9 + 11 = 388129 + 625 + 625 + 625 + 529 + 81 + 11 = 390625. $$

With $n=33$ we get $K=12, W=16, $ $ \; \; 33^4 = 1185921,$ then
$$ 1087^2 + 33^2 + 33^2 + 33^2 + 31^2 + 9 \cdot 12 + 16 = 1181569 + 1089 + 1089 + 1089 + 961 + 108 + 16 = 1185921. $$

Comment: So for example, take $x_4=\cdots=x_n=1$ and represent $n^4-n+3$ as the sum of three odd squares.

Comment: @GregMartin added in a (mostly) greedy solution at the end that could be found by a student who did not know Gauss's result.